# How to define a custom filter and bind it to a resource endpoint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

I'm using Python EVE, EVE-SQLAlchemy, Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, SQLAlchemy and a Postgres database.

I have my API endpoints all setup and they are working fine out the box.

Now i'm trying to filter the items returned by the *some_model* resource so that it only returns items (GET) that belong to a certain user (the user doing the API request) or have a certain name (prefix). The SQlAlcehmy code to perform this is below:

```
session.query(SomeModel).filter(or_(SomeModel.name.like('SOMETHING_%'), SomeModel.account_id==1)).all()
```

I've looked at pre and post request hooks, User-Restricted Resource Access and everything else I could find, but nowhere seems to describe how to apply custom filters to (all) GET requests of a certain endpoint/resource.

Kind of like the URL filter functionality, but always on and filtering at the database level, not the serialization/response level.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, looks like a [Dynamic Lookup Filter](http://python-eve.org/features.html#dynamic-lookup-filters) inside a [Pre-Request Event Hook](http://python-eve.org/features.html#pre-request-event-hooks) will work for your filtering needs.

Comment: Have you managed to make the event hook to be called just before `SomeModel` `GET` calls? If so you just need to change lookup filter there (I don't know how EVE-SQLAlchemy syntax is).

I have no environment to test EVE-SQLAlchemy, so my example would be using standard mongo lookups. I can post a working code for MongoDB if that helps.

Comment: I have yes, but there is no access to the sql alchemy query object. I can't work out the sqlalchemy filters either. Curently I have added another hook as a pre_query hook that exposes the cursor and thus query object which you can then modify. Seems to be working nicely, but a 'proper' or supported method would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact syntax for `like` query, but `or` can be achieved like so: (I have tested it, it works)

```
def pre_GET(resource, request, lookup):
    # only return documents for account_id 1 or where name is metalstorm
    lookup['or_'] = [{'account_id': 1}, {'name': 'metalstorm'}]
```

For `like` query, see if [this](https://github.com/RedTurtle/eve-sqlalchemy/blob/master/eve_sqlalchemy/parser.py#L101) helps.